# String Pattern in R

Tags: r, string

I have a list of strings as follow: "/home/ricardo/MultiClass/data//F10/1036.txt"

```
>     library(stringr)   
>     strsplit(cls[1], split= "/")
```

Give me:

```
#> [[1]] [1] ""           "home"       "ricardo"    "MultiClass" "data"  
#> ""           "F10"        "1036.txt"
```

How can I keep only the 7th position?

```
#> "F10"
```

Comment: How can you identify it? Because it is preceded with `//`?

Comment: If by position, then `strsplit(cls[1], split= "/")[[1]][7]` should work.

Comment: How about `basename(dirname(cls[1]))`

Comment: `strsplit` is a base R function, not in *stringr*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to extract one or more chars after `//` up to the first `/` or end of string use

```
> library(stringr) 
> s <- "/home/ricardo/MultiClass/data//F10/1036.txt"
> str_extract(s, "(?<=//)[^/]+")
[1] "F10"
```

The `(?<=//)[^/]+` regex pattern will find a position that is preceded with 2 slashes (see `(?<=//)`) and then matches one or more characters other than `/` (see `[^/]+`).

A base R solution with `sub` will look like

```
> sub("^.*/([^/]*)/[^/]*$", "\\1", s)
[1] "F10"
```

**Details**:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*` - any 0+ chars as many as possible
- `/` - a slash (last but one in the string as the previous pattern is greedy)
- `([^/]*)` - capturing group #1 matching any 0+ chars other than `/`
- `/` - last slash
- `[^/]*` - any 0+ chars other than `/`
- `$` - end of string.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done in R-base in this way.
I have defined the function `gret` to extract a pattern from a string

```
gret <-function(pattern,text,ignore.case=TRUE){
    regmatches(text,regexpr(pattern,text,perl=TRUE,ignore.case))
```

then

```
gsub("data|/*","",gret("(?=data/).*(?<=/)","/home/ricardo/MultiClass
/data//F10/1036.txt"))


#>[1] "F10"
```

Comment: Thanks all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Using function `word` of `stringr`,

```
library(stringr)
word(sub('.*//', '', s), 1, sep = '/')
#[1] "F10"

#where
s <- '/home/ricardo/MultiClass/data//F10/1036.txt'
```